# Community bot overly aggressive at auto-deleting questions

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing questions that I've asked on various stack exchanges and one of my biology [questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23188/4788) inexplicably disappeared. Until I realised that the *Community* bot auto-deleted it as inactive!

This level of aggression from an auto-deleting bot is especially egregious considering that insufficent time was provided for me to follow up on this question and re-word it in a fashion that *biology.se* members were willing to answer. For the mechanism of action for emotions in the human brain is not unfathomable; nor in 100+ years of pharmaceutical literature is it unlikely that such psycho-suppessive agents haven't been encountered.

Answer (score 5):

The rules for automatic deletion that led to your question being deleted are the following:

> - Automatic deletion of closed, abandoned questions for questions meeting the following criteria:
>
>   - Closed more than 9 days ago
>   - Not closed as a duplicate
>   - Score <= 0
>   - Not locked
>   - No answers with a score > 0
>   - No accepted answer
>   - No pending reopen votes
>   - No edits in the past 9 days

The question ([link for 2k+ users](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23188/if-a-drug-exists-or-could-exist-that-eliminates-human-emotion-what-would-be-its)) was closed on the same day as it was asked. It was then deleted 10 days later. The question was not edited in those 10 days, I don't think it is unreasonable to interpret this as "inactive".

Comment: Related to the recent dicussion [here](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/763/what-is-to-be-done-with-questions-that-have-no-answers-yet/777#777); does this mean that closed Qs with a score>0 are never automatically deleted, even if they have no answers and no matter how old they are?

Comment: @fileunderwater [This is the full list of criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/151385), upvoted questions are generally not deleted automatically. That is something the community has to do manually.